# jquery is not define flexslider in magento 2.2.0

Tags: error, magento2.2, frontend

```
jquery.flexslider-min.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery.flexslider-min.js:5
(anonymous) @ jquery.flexslider-min.js:5
17:11:53.194 (index):917 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).flexslider is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):917)
    at fire (jquery.js:3232)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3362)
    at ready (jquery.js:3582)
```

> app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {          
            flexsliderjs: 'Vendor_Modulename/js/jquery.flexslider-min'
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    paths: {            
            'flexsliderjs': 'Vendor_Modulename/js/jquery.flexslider-min'
        },   
    shim: {
        'flexsliderjs': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
}
```

> app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/templates/phtml file

```
require(['jquery','flexsliderjs'],function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){   
       alert('hi');
    }); 
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep below content in your `requirejs-config.js` file,

```
var config = {
    paths: {            
            'flexsliderjs': 'Vendor_Modulename/js/jquery.flexslider-min'
        },   
    shim: {
        'flexsliderjs': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
}
```

Run deployment command

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify jQuery dependency for that flexslider JS. As per below code. Then remove var and pub/static folder. At last run deploy command again to check it.

```
var config = {
    paths: {            
            'flexsliderjs': 'Vendor_Modulename/js/jquery.flexslider-min'
        },   
    shim: {
        'flexsliderjs': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
}
```